# Probability of Events with Complement

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let E and F be events with P(E) = .3, P(F) = .6, and P(E ∪ F) = .7. Find

(a) P(E ∩ F)
(b) P(E|F) 
(c) P(F|E) 
(d) P(E^c ∩ F) 
(e) P(E^c|F)

COMMENT: for (a) I got .2 since P(E ∪ F)= P(E) + P(F) - P(E ∩ F). 
so .3 plus .6 equals .9, and .9-.7=.2.

(b) P(E|F)= P(E ∩ F)/P(F), so .2/.4=.5

For the rest I am sorta confused.

Comment: Please choose a title specific to the question. In particular, avoid generic words like "question" that apply to all posts on this site and thus waste space. Similarly, a probability is always a probability of events. Also, the title should not simply mirror the tags ([tag:probability]), which are broad categories, but should describe the question more specifically.

Comment: Hint: use the definition of conditional probability.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly (c) and (e) are solved similarly to (b).

---

Now (d) is solved through the Law of Total Probability.   For any two events $X,Y$, it will be that: $$\mathsf P(X)=\mathsf P(X\cap Y)+\mathsf P(X\cap Y^\complement)$$